# How to use the output of "route print" to set a specific network cards parameters?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

i am on a windows 7 system in the command line / batch file.
there i can get the index of my network cards by parsing the output of "route print":

```
route print | findstr "Microsoft\ Virtual\ WiFi\ Miniport\ Adapter\ #4"
```

this gives me the output:

```
 22...58 94 6b 0f 87 65 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #4
```

from this output i need to get the number 22 so that i can reuse it in my script this way:

```
set IP1=21
# 22 has to be replaced by the output of the "route print":
set IP2=22 

netsh interface ipv4 set address %IP1% static %M_IP% %MASK% gateway=%GW% gwmetric=1
```

the variables %M_IP% %MASK% and %GW% are set in the batch file too.

[Edit at 2016-10-17]: 
using the accepted answer i get a script like this:

```
@echo off
echo Suche Netzwerkkarten fuer Masterunit V1


echo suche erste Karte:
echo - Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection

for /f "tokens=1 delims=. " %%a in ('route print ^| findstr /C:"Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection"') do set "IP1_1=%%a"
if  "%IP1_1%"=="" goto l1
echo %IP1_1%
goto l1a
:l1
echo keine Karte gefunden
:l1a
echo suche zweite Karte:
echo - Intel(R) 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection

for /f "tokens=1 delims=. " %%a in ('route print ^| findstr /C:"Intel(R) 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection"') do set "IP1_2=%%a"
if  "%IP1_2%"=="" goto l2
echo %IP1_2%
goto l2a
:l2
echo keine Karte gefunden
:l2a
echo Suche Netzwerkkarten fuer Masterunit V2 / flexE12CM2K:

echo suche erste Karte:
echo - Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connection

for /f "tokens=1 delims=. " %%a in ('route print ^| findstr /C:"Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connection"') do set "IP2_1=%%a"
if  "%IP2_1%"=="" goto l3
echo %IP2_1%
goto l3a
:l3
echo keine Karte gefunden
:l3a
echo suche zweite Karte:
echo - Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I218-LM

for /f "tokens=1 delims=. " %%a in ('route print ^| findstr /C:"Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I218-LM"') do set "IP2_2=%%a"
if  "%IP2_2%"=="" goto l4
echo %IP2_2%
goto l4a
:l4
echo keine Karte gefunden
:l4a
echo alles nochmal zusammen gefasst:

echo Masterunit V1: 1. Karte : %IP1_1%
echo Masterunit V1: 2. Karte : %IP1_2%
echo Masterunit V2: 1. Karte : %IP2_1%
echo Masterunit V2: 2. Karte : %IP2_2%
```

Is it possible to rename the network interfaces (IP1_1 may be named "LAN-Verbindung 2", while IP1_2 is named "LAN-Verbindung") and it should always be that IP1_1 must be named "ETH_EXT" and IP1_2 must be named "ETH_MSR".

The same applies for the pair IP2_1 and IP2_2, because those two interface cards denote another hardware configuration.

But i cannot find a way to rename the interfaces when using the indexes. And the indexes are the only reference to the interfaces itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for /f "tokens=1 delims=. " %a in ('route print ^| findstr /C:"Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #4"') do set "IP=%a"

Be carefull with processing "route print" output, if specific network card is disabled  for some reason, interface will not be listed here.

Comment: Thank you, that works fine. If I check IP for a blank string, i know when it is disabled or not present at all.